# Why won't my delete function respond to the button?

Tags: php

I have a problem my delete function does not work he does not delete the organisation. When I press the button it show the text if I want to delete it I say yes but it only refreshes the site. I am not an advanced programmer and some of the code I did not write myself someone else worked on the project before me so idk why he some codes are written this way and he did not use any framework.

My code

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
        if (isset($_FILES['croppedImage'])) logoChange();
        // change organisation information is not made yet
        if (isset($_POST['update'])) echo "This function is not made yet!"; 
        if (isset($_POST['deleteOrganisation'])) DeleteOrganisations();
         
    }
//this is the logoChange function
    function logoChange() {
        include '../../../include/db_conn.php';
        //get organisation_id
        $organisation_id = $_POST['organisation_id'];
        //blob file info
        $fileName = $_FILES['croppedImage']['name'];
        $fileTmpName = $_FILES['croppedImage']['tmp_name'];
        $fileSize = $_FILES['croppedImage']['size'];
        $fileError = $_FILES['croppedImage']['error'];
        //change blob to png
        $fileType = 'png';
        
        //check if image is able to upload
        if ($fileError === 0) {
            //check if file is not too big change number to needs!
            if ($fileSize < 1000000) {
                //make new random filename
                $fileNameNew = uniqid('', true).".".$fileType;
                $fileDesination = '../../../img/uploads/'.$fileNameNew;
                move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDesination);

                //check if organisation already has a logo
                $get_organisation_stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT `organisation_logo` FROM `organisations` WHERE `organisation_id` = ?');
                $get_organisation_stmt->bind_param('s', $organisation_id);
                $get_organisation_stmt->execute();
                $result_organisation = $get_organisation_stmt->get_result();
                $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_organisation);

                if (is_null($row['organisation_logo'])) {
                    //if not inserted it
                    $sqlUpdateLogo = 'UPDATE `organisations` SET `organisation_logo`="'.$fileNameNew.'" WHERE `organisation_id` ="'.$organisation_id.'"';
                    mysqli_query($conn, $sqlUpdateLogo);
                    echo 'image inserted';
                } else {
                    //else replace it
                    unlink('../../../img/uploads/'.$row['organisation_logo']);
                    $sqlUpdateLogo = 'UPDATE `organisations` SET `organisation_logo`="'.$fileNameNew.'" WHERE `organisation_id` ="'.$organisation_id.'"';
                    mysqli_query($conn, $sqlUpdateLogo);
                    echo 'image replaced';
                }
            }
            else {
                echo "File to big";
            }
        } else {
            echo "Error in file";
        }

    }
// here i made the delete function
    function DeleteOrganisations() {
        include '../../../include/db_conn.php';
        //delete the organisation 
        $getDeleteOrganisation = $_POST['deleteOrganisation'];
        $delete_organisation_stmt = $conn->prepare('DELETE FROM `organisations` WHERE `organisation_id`= ?');
        $delete_organisation_stmt->bind_param('i', $getDeleteOrganisation);
        $delete_organisation_stmt->execute();
        $delete_organisation_stmt->close(); 
    }
```

here are the functions and here is JavaScript

```
//link for datatable functions
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#organisations').DataTable({
        "columnDefs": [
            { "orderable": false, "targets": [0, 5] }
        ],
        "order": [[ 1, "asc" ]]
    });
});

//open edit modal for logo
$(document).on("click", ".btnopenEditLogo", function(e) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var organisationId = $(this).val();
    var url = "functions/getOrganisationActions.php";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url : url,
        data: {'HiddenLogoid': organisationId},
        success: function (data) {
            $('#myLogoEditModal').modal('show');
            $("#myLogoEditModal .modal-body").html(data);
        }
    });
});

//open modal with info of user for editing
$(document).on("click", ".btnopenEditOrganisation", function(e) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var organisationId = $(this).val();
    var url = "functions/getOrganisationActions.php";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url : url,
        data: {'HiddenOrganisationid': organisationId},
        success: function (data) {
            $('#myOrganisationEditModal').modal('show');
            $("#myOrganisationEditModal .modal-body").html(data);
        }
    });
});

//delete organisation
$(document).on("click", ".btnRemoveOrganisation", function(e) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var remove = $(this).val();
    var url = "../cms/organisations/functions/postOrganisationActions.php";
    
    Swal.fire({
        title: 'Delete this test?',
        text: "If you delete the test the questions and all statistics will be lost!",
        type: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
        cancelButtonText: 'No, cancel!',
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33'
    }).then((result) => {
            if (result.value) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url : url,
                    data: {'deleteOrganisation': remove},
                    success: function (data) {
                        Swal.fire({
                            title: 'Deleted!',
                            text: "You deleted the survey!",
                            type: 'success',
                            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                            confirmButtonText: 'OK'
                        }).then((result) => {
                            if (result.value) {
                            window.location.reload();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            } else if (result.dismiss === Swal.DismissReason.cancel) {
                Swal.fire (
                    'Cancelled',
                    'Your test is safe :)',
                    'error'
                )
            }
    });
});
```

this is the index

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if (!isset($_SESSION["userId"])) {
        header('Location: ../../auth/login');
        die();
    }

    $activePage = "cms";
    $activeCMSTab = "organisations";
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Admin CMS | Organisations</title>
        <!-- include header -->
        <?php require '../../include/header.php'; ?>
    </head>
    <body class="d-flex flex-column">
        <!-- include navbar -->
        <?php require '../../include/navbar.php'; ?>
        <!-- include organisation functions -->
        <?php require 'functions/getOrganisationsActions.php'; ?>

        <div id="main">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div  id="sidenav-border" class="col-lg-3 d-none d-md-none d-lg-block">
                        <?php require '../../include/cms_sidenav.php'; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-9">
                        <div class="card-theme mt-3">
                            <div class="clearfix">
                                <h5 class="card-title-theme float-left"><i class="fas fa-building"></i> Organisation list:</h5>
                                <a  href="../manual" class="card-tool-theme"><i class="fas fa-info-circle fa-fw mt-2 mr-2"></i></a>
                            </div>
                            <hr class="hr-theme" />
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <?php getOrganisations(); ?>      
                            </div>   
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- footer -->
        <?php require '../../include/footer.php'; ?>
        <!-- logo modal -->
        <?php require 'logo-edit-modal.php'; ?>
        <!-- organisation modal -->
        <?php require 'organisation-edit-modal.php'; ?>
        <!-- logout modal -->
        <?php require '../../auth/logout-modal.php'; ?> 
        <!-- include js scripts -->
        <script src="js/organisationFunctions.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

you need get organisation where the button is made the button is at

```
<?php

function getOrganisations() {
    //include DataBase connection
    include '../../include/db_conn.php';

    //show every organisation that is approved
    $sqlCollectAllOrganisations = "SELECT * FROM `organisations` WHERE `approval_admin`='1'";
    $resultAllOrganisations = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlCollectAllOrganisations);

    echo    '<div class="table-responsive">';
    echo        '<table id="organisations" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">';
    echo            '<thead>';
    echo                '<tr>';  
    echo                  '<th>Logo</th>';    
    echo                  '<th>Organisation</th>'; 
    echo                  '<th>Parent</th>';  
    echo                  '<th>type</th>';        
    echo                  '<th>Users</th>';    
    echo                  '<th>Tools</th>';    
    echo              '</tr>';  
    echo          '</thead>';
    echo          '<tbody>';
    //Show organisations 
    if ($resultAllOrganisations->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $resultAllOrganisations-> fetch_assoc()) {
          echo '<tr>';

          //organisation logo
          if ($row['organisation_logo'] == '')
            echo      '<td class="align-middle" align="center"><img src="../../img/stock/no-image-icon.png" class="rounded d-inline mr-1" width="30px"></img><button class="btn btn-link d-inline p-0 btnopenEditLogo" value="'. $row['organisation_id'] .'">edit</button></td>'; 
          else 
            echo      '<td class="align-middle" align="center"><img src="../../img/uploads/'. $row['organisation_logo'] .'" class="rounded border d-inline mr-1" width="30px"><button class="btn btn-link d-inline p-0 btnopenEditLogo" value="'. $row['organisation_id'] .'">edit</button></td>';  
          

          //organisation name
          echo      '<td class="align-middle">' .$row['organisation_name']. '</td>';

          //organisation parent
          if ($row['organisation_parent'] != null) { 
            $sqlCollectparent = "SELECT * FROM `organisations` WHERE `organisation_id`='".$row['organisation_parent']."'";
            $resultparent = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlCollectparent);
              if ($parent = $resultparent-> fetch_assoc()) echo '<td class="align-middle">'.$parent['organisation_name'].'</td>'; 
          } else {
            echo '<td class="align-middle"><i class="fas fa-times" style="font-size: 16px;"></i></td>';
          }
          
          //organisation type
          echo      '<td class="align-middle">' . $row['organisation_type'] . '</td>';  

          //count users
          $sqlCountUsers = "SELECT COUNT(organisation_id) AS `count` FROM `users` WHERE `organisation_id`='".$row['organisation_id']."'";
          $resultcount = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlCountUsers);
          if ($count = $resultcount-> fetch_assoc()) echo '<td class="align-middle">'.$count['count'].'</td>'; 
          //buttons
          echo      '<td class="align-middle text-center">';
          echo          '<div class="btn-group">'; 
          echo          '<button class="btn-theme btn-theme-success btn-theme-sm mr-1">Add user</button>';
          echo          '<button class="btn-theme btn-theme-primary btn-theme-sm mr-1 btnopenEditOrganisation" value="'. $row['organisation_id'] .'"><i class="fas fa-edit fa-fw"></i></button>'; 
                          if ($_SESSION['organisation_id'] != $row['organisation_id']) echo '<button type="button" class="btn-theme btn-theme-danger btn-theme-sm btnRemoveOrganisation" value=""><i class="fas fa-trash-alt fa-fw"></i></button>';
          echo        '</div>';
          echo      '</td>';  
          echo '</tr>';
        }
    } else {
      //do nothing
    }
    echo          '</tbody>';
    echo        '</table>';
    echo    '</div>';
  }

?>
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Is this a JS problem, or a PHP problem?

Comment: Also, be warned that your code contains SQL queries that are vulnerable to SQL injection

Comment: Hey @Doku, do you have any console errors in your browser? Or PHP errors - either on the browser or on your log file? This *could* narrow your problem down to more specific problems.

Comment: You have a click handler on `.btnRemoveOrganisation` there. So inside of that, what exactly did you expect `$(this).val()` to return now, considering the HTML of that element contains `value=""` …?

Comment: @Sam, i have no errors in the console thats why i dont know now why it does not work

Comment: @NicoHaase the deletefunction works i made another function it looks like this but it works over there but not here  here it only refreshes the site

Comment: @CBroe i put this inside `value="'. $row['organisation_id'] .'"` i forgot i dont really know why i am doing this to be honest i dont really know how this whole code is written and works someone else worked on it first and i cant contact him so i dont understand why he did this. earlier it worked but now it doesnt so idk.

Comment: It might be worth doing a `var_dump($getDeleteOrganisation);` inside your delete function to see if you're actually posting what you expect it to post. If you don't get a value from that there must be an issue with your js or html. I'm not familiar with sweet alert so you could also do a `console.log(organisationId);`  inside your js to make sure you are posting that value

Comment: @Brennii96 i did the var_dump and i did not get a value where in js should i post the console.log

Comment: @Doku if you do `console.log(remove);` just below this line in your js `var remove = $(this).val();` you will see if that var is correct. Now you know your PHP isn't receiving the value you know it's either a HTML or JS issue

Comment: @Brennii96 sorry for responding late i did the console.log(remove) after i press the button i get organisationFunctions.js:47 and that is it it is not in a red colour but if i do console.log(organisationId) i get an error code: Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: organisationId is not defined
    at organisationFunctions.js:73

Comment: @Brennii96 if i put the console log organisationId at the same place as the consolelog remove i get this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: organisationId is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (organisationFunctions.js:47)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.r.handle (jquery.min.js:2)